# How to replace characters inplace fast using C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file (66GB) where I would like to replace some characters. I can't load the whole thing into memory.

This is the basic idea of what I was hoping to do:

```
std::ifstream i(infile.c_str()); // ifsteam 
while(i.good()) {
    getline(i, line); 
    for(int c=0;c<line.length();c++) {
        if(line[c]=='Q')
            // *** REPLACE Q WITH X HERE
    }
}
```

My question is: how do I put the new character so that is actually replaces Q?

Subquestion: is there a better / faster way to do this?

---

I am working on a virtual ubuntu server: 2 Cores, 4GB of memory, OS is ubuntu.

Comment: `line[c] = 'X';`

Comment: Probably worth looking at [std::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace).

Comment: @Galik I would like to change the file as well, this will replace the character in the string but not in the file, right? I would like to change the file in place.

Comment: On which operating system, which file system, what kind of computer (laptop or supercomputer) and disk?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch its a rather weak virtual machine running x86 ubuntu and HDD storage.

Comment: That should go in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did, perhaps the question did not refresh?

Comment: BTW what kind of application are you coding (bioinformatics perhaps,)? What kind of data are you processing? Where does it come from? Perhaps rethinking all of it and using some database (or [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/)...) might improve things.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch bioinformatics is a good guess :) its simpler though: I am scrambling some sensitive info inside db-dumps for data protection reasons.

Comment: Then working with the genuine DB could be more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this which I would think would be faster.

```
std::ifstream ifs("input_file_name", std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream ofs("output_file_name", std::ios::binary);

char buf[4096]; // larger = faster (within limits)

while(ifs.read(buf, sizeof(buf)) || ifs.gcount())
{
    // replace the characters
    std::replace(buf, buf + ifs.gcount(), 'Q', 'X');

    // write to a new file
    ofs.write(buf, ifs.gcount());
}
```

If you don't want to produce a separate file (more dangerous) then you could modify the original file something a bit like this **(untested code)**:

```
std::fstream fs("input_file_name", std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

char buf[4096]; // larger = faster (within limits)

auto beg = fs.tellg();

while(fs.read(buf, sizeof(buf)) || fs.gcount())
{
    auto end = fs.tellg();

    // replace the characters
    std::replace(buf, buf + fs.gcount(), 'Q', 'X');

    // return to start of block
    fs.seekp(beg);

    // overwrite this block
    fs.write(buf, fs.gcount());

    // shift old beginning to the end
    beg = end;

    // go to new beginning to start reading the next block
    fs.seekg(beg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if I have to use a second file I will do this. Is there perhaps a way to do this in place?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't practically improve the performance in a significant way. You have an IO bound not CPU bound problem. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46617570/841108)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think it is not unreasonable to expect that increasing the buffer size from the size of an average line to `4096` or beyond may well add something to the performance. Especially between reading and writing operations. Think of all the (several millisecond) seek operations you will save.

Comment: It would slightly improve, but not much.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace the characters *in the file* and not only in the data you read, then it's not as simple as one would think.

The simplest and probably also quickest way is to read the data in chunks into memory, replace the data in the memory chunk, and write it out to a temporary file. Then when done, you rename the temporary file as the original file.

Comment: thank you! I don't have enough space in memory, but Galiks method to do it in chunks works find.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably better to avoid the C++ IO system and use the C memory mapped IO system.  You will have to add in error handling code but this should give you a start.

```
/// Access a file using the mmap/munmap functions
///
class mmap_file
{
private:
  char * data_;
  std::size_t size_;
  int fd_;

public:  
  ~mmap_file()
  {
     ::munmap( this->data_, this->size_ );
     ::close( this->fd_ );
  }
  mmap_file( std::string fname ): data_( 0 )
    , size_( 0 )
    , fd_( -1 )
  {
     this->fd_ = ::open( fname.c_str(), O_RDWR );
     ::off_t tmp = ::lseek( this->fd_, 0, SEEK_END );
     this->size_ = ( size_t )tmp;
     tmp = ::lseek( this->fd_, 0, SEEK_SET );
     this->data_ = ::mmap( NULL, this->size_, PROT_WRITE
                         , MAP_PRIVATE, this->fd_, 0 );
  }

  // Is object valid?
  bool is_valid() const
  {
    return (char*)(0) != this->data_;
  }

  // Access the data of the object.
  char* const data()
  {
    return this->data_;
  }

  // What is the size of the object (in bytes)
  std::size_t size() const
  {
    return this->size_;
  }
};
```

Then

```
mmap_file mmfile( "some_filename" );
if (mmfile.is_valid())
{
  for( char* p = mmfile.data(); p != mmfile.data() + mmfile.size(); ++p )
  {
    if( *p == 'Q' ) *p = 'X';
  }
}
```

This allows you to read and write the file from the same object. The C++ iostream is more designed to read from one object and write to another which is not so useful for editing in place.  In addition the memory mapped IO uses the computer's memory paging system to handle reading and writing to disk making this efficient on very large files.

You could improve the shown class by adding `begin` and `end` methods, then the shown for loop can be replaced with `std::replace`.

**NOTE** Because this uses the OS memory paging system it will recognise which pages have had alterations and which not and automatically only save altered pages to disk (with generally a 4096 byte granularity).  You can do this manually with the other manual buffering answers but it requires more work from you.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code is good enough.** Don't forget to compile it with optimizations enabled (e.g. `g++ -O2 -march=native` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

Some implementations of C++ standard libraries are done above C standard library. Then perhaps coding your thing in C (with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)) might be very slightly faster.

Perhaps using [std::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) might be slightly faster.

**The bottleneck remains the disk IO** itself (and the hardware!) and you won't change that. Check with [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) that your program is I/O bound (or spend a lot of time in system CPU time, e.g. doing system calls). If you can afford it, get some better hardware (e.g. SSD disks if you have spinning hard disks).

On Linux, you might use low level system calls like [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html). You could avoid standard library functions and use directly system calls like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) (with a large enough buffer of e.g. 64Kbytes or one megabyte) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html). If you just need to replace characters in place (without changing the file size) e.g. replace `Q`by `A`, that could be (very slightly) faster.

On most computers (except costly servers having a terabyte of RAM), a 66 Gbyte file don't stay in  the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). So the problem is IO bound.

But if, as I suspect, your code is I/O bound and spend most of its time doing I/O (e.g. waiting for the disk or running system calls), improvement of your code won't really matter. You'll win at most a few percent of elapsed real time (which is what actually matters to you). You could perhaps even use existing commands like [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) to get the work done.

Remember that IO on spinning disk takes a dozen of milliseconds (per sectors of few kilobytes); with an SSD it could be a hundred microseconds. CPU can process a word of 8 bytes in a nanosecond.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. One of my problems was to actually do the write in place. Seems to work now.